# Android Studio not able to find drawable resource for ImageView

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-studio-3.0, android-designer

I am using Android Studio 3.0.1, I have a simple xml file with root `ConstraintLayout`, so when I do preview and `drag and drop` an `ImageView` from the `Preview` `Palette`, it is not able to find the new added png file, which I have copy/paste directly in the project directory, not in `Android Studio.`

[image]

I have tried clean, rebuild but it is still not able to find the image.

I know that it will work if I `restart` it but I think that it is not a good idea to `restart` each and every time I add a new png file.

Is this a bug in `Android Studio`?

Have anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Use `project` mode and copy-paste image

Answer (score 1):

File - Sync with file system may help. Looking at your file names above, they should be ok as I hit the same problem due to using an upper case char at the start of the filename.

By building the project, I was alerted to this by the following error:
"H is not a valid file-based resource name character: File-based resource names must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9, or underscore"

Answer (score 0):

Drawable folder host images, so try putting your images in this folder when using imageView.

A workaround for images organization (since the project's folder structure should prevail flat) is using underscore rather that forward dash.